# How do I define methods in Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm new to Javascript, I'm working on a small game to get a better handle of it. I'm trying to define a character object with methods, but for some reason I'm getting weird errors from my IDE, "Label 'updateHealth' on function statement, Missing name in function declaration". I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. In my code, display is how the character's health display's on the screen.

```
  function Character(display) {
    this.health = 100;
    this.display = display;


    // updates the health on the screen
    updateHealth: function() {
       if(health == 100) {
         this.display.innerText = 'HP: ' + health;
    }
    else if(health > 10 && health < 100) {
      this.display.innerText = 'HP: 0' + health;
    }
    else if(health < 10 && health > 0) {
      this.display.innerText = 'HP: 00' + health;
    }
    else {
      this.display.innerText = 'HP: 000';
    }
  }

  // returns true if character has died
  checkForDeath: function() {
    if(health <= 0) return true;
    else return false;
  }

  // function used when damage is inflicted on
  // a character object
  takeDamange: function(damage) {
    this.health -= damage;
  }

  // handles the four possible moves
  // opponent is null because if player heals
  // then it does not make sense for there to be
  // an opponent
  makeMove: function(move, opponent=null) {
    switch(move) {
      case 'PUNCH':
        opponent.takeDamage(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 10);
        opponent.updateHealth();
        break;
      case 'HEAL':
        this.health += 20;
        break;
      case 'KICK':
        opponent.takeDamage(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 20);
        opponent.updateHealth();
        break;
      case 'EXTERMINATE':
        opponent.takeDamage(opponent.health);
        opponent.updateHealth();
        break;
    }

    return opponent.checkForDeath();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the `class` syntax?

Comment: Does renaming `takeDamange` to `takeDamage` help?

Comment: @APerson no, but I missed that, thank you

Comment: @jhpratt what's class syntax? I just read through the MDN javascript guide and it suggest that this was the only way to make classes

Comment: How are you calling `makeMove`? We can't see it in this code sample.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: @jhpratt Wait, there are standard classes? I was reading through their javascript guide and on that they told me to use the function syntax. I redid my code with the class syntax and the the errors went away. Thanks, man.

Comment: Probem is with your definition of the methods of the constructor function. While every function is an object, to add a function as a method of a constructor function, you have to define it using the `this` notation, ergo: `this.updateHealth = function()...`

Comment: @ZackaryF _Technically_ it's massive syntactic sugar, but yes, there is a syntax that uses the `class` keyword.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the class keyword? Is it significantly less efficient or something?

Comment: @jhpratt It's relatively small sugar, actually.

Comment: @ZackaryF No, there's no technical reason not to use it unless you need to support relatively old browsers. Even then it's a relatively simple transformation, but getting the mechanics of that can be a little daunting.

Comment: @ZackaryF Not really, it's been widely supported for a while now. I've posted an answer using the class syntax and some refactoring.

Comment: @ZackaryF Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Object's can be instantiated via a constructor function such as your `Character()` function however, you'll need to ensure object methods (such as `updateHealth()`, etc) are "attached" to the instance of the character object.

One way to achieve that is via the `this` keyword:

```
/* Attach the checkForDeath() function as a method of "this" Character instance */
this.checkForDeath = function() {

  /* Accessing "this" corresponds to the instance of the character object */
  if (this.health <= 0) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

By making these changes, `checkForDeath()` is now defined as a member function of the corresponding `character` instance. You'll need to ensure that you access fields on the instance via `this`, as shown on this line  `if(this.health <= 0) { ... }`

You'll also need to ensure that you instantiate instances of `Character` via the `new` operator like this:

```
const characterInstance =  new Character( someElement );
```

Here is a revised version of your code demonstrating this approach:

```js
function Character(display) {
  this.health = 100;
  this.display = display;

  this.updateHealth = function() {
    const health = this.health; /* Add this */
    if (this.health == 100) { 
      this.display.innerText = 'HP: ' + health;
    } else if (health > 10 && health < 100) {
      this.display.innerText = 'HP: 0' + health;
    } else if (health < 10 && health > 0) {
      this.display.innerText = 'HP: 00' + health;
    } else {
      this.display.innerText = 'HP: 000';
    }
  }
  
  this.checkForDeath = function() {
    if (this.health <= 0) return true;
    else return false;
  }

  this.takeDamange = function(damage) {
 
    this.health -= damage;
  }
  
  this.makeMove = function(move, opponent = null) {
    switch (move) {
      case 'PUNCH':
        opponent.takeDamage(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 10);
        opponent.updateHealth();
        break;
      case 'HEAL':
        this.health += 20;
        break;
      case 'KICK':
        opponent.takeDamage(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 20);
        opponent.updateHealth();
        break;
      case 'EXTERMINATE':
        opponent.takeDamage(opponent.health);
        opponent.updateHealth();
        break;
    }

    return opponent.checkForDeath();
  }
}

const player =  new Character( document.querySelector('p') );
player.takeDamange();
player.updateHealth();
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `:` to `=`, and assign it to a local property, such as

```
this.updateHealth = function() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: your solution would lead to the functions being available in the global scope.  Consequent upon this, the `this` would be not be primarily tied to instances of the `Character` constructor function, but to whatever object the method is invoked on.

Comment: Thanks NaijaProgrammer. I was trying to point out that it needs to be assigned to a property when defining inside another function. I will update to include this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `class` syntax.

```js
class Character {
    constructor(display) {
        this.health = 100;
        this.display = display;
    }

    // updates the health on the screen
    updateHealth() {
        this.display.innerText = `HP: ${Math.max(health, 0).toString().padStart(3, '0')}`;
    }

    // returns true if character has died
    checkForDeath() {
        return health <= 0;
    }

    // function used when damage is inflicted on
    // a character object
    takeDamange(damage) {
        this.health -= damage;
    }

    // handles the four possible moves
    // opponent is null because if player heals
    // then it does not make sense for there to be
    // an opponent
    makeMove(move, opponent = null) {
        switch (move) {
            case 'PUNCH':
                opponent.takeDamage(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 10);
                opponent.updateHealth();
                break;
            case 'HEAL':
                this.health += 20;
                break;
            case 'KICK':
                opponent.takeDamage(parseInt(Math.random() * 100) % 20);
                opponent.updateHealth();
                break;
            case 'EXTERMINATE':
                opponent.takeDamage(opponent.health);
                opponent.updateHealth();
                break;
        }

        return opponent.checkForDeath();
    }
}
```

I also did some slight refactoring, which should make it easier to understand what is happening.